# How to use CUFFT from Fortran 90?

Tags: binding, cuda, fortran, fft, fortran90

How to use **CUFFT library** (from nVidia's CUDA SDK 4.0.13), which as far as I know has only C bindings, in program written in **Fortran 90** (to be compiled using `gfortran` from GNU Compiler Colection 4.4.5)?

I am interested in both 1d and 2d FFT calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You need a C source file as delegate which follows a special naming regime for the functions to be callable form Fortran. In the delegate functions you call the CudaFFT functions.

Details can be found here:

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html

Comment: That tutorial is about older **Fortran 77**. I was specifically asking about **Fortran 90** which has `interface` keyword and `iso_c_binding` module.

Comment: @Jakub: The `iso_c_binding` module was not introduced until fortran 2003. You explicitly specified fortran 90. If you're project allows you to use `iso_c_binding`, that's definitely the way to go, and since you know about that, I don't understand the point of your question; the answer is simply (as you already seem to know) 'use `iso_c_binding`'.

Comment: I'm just beginning to use new Fortran features (I used Fortran 77 before), so I didn't know that `iso_c_binding` and `bind(C, name='foo')` is Fortran 2003 feature.